# Issue in using fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

Hi i have a xml layout which I have included as a fragment in every layout.

Here is my xml in maincategories.xml

```
             <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/mainbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/logo"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />
        </LinearLayout>
 <View
    android:id="@+id/viewLine"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/txtUserName"
    android:background="#cccccc" />
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:divider="#b5b5b5"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true" />
    <fragment 
     android:name="com.rag.xmlparsing.fragmentactivity"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      />

 </LinearLayout>
```

the java code for the above xml is

```
public class Listofcategories extends Activity {

            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.maincategories);
            // some code for list activity
         }
```

And fragmentactivity class is

```
public class fragmentactivity extends FragmentActivity {
RadioButton radioButton;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
          Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.actnavbar,
            container, false);


        radioButton = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.home);
        radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(btnNavBarOnCheckedChangeListener);
        radioButton = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.aboutus);
        radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(btnNavBarOnCheckedChangeListener);
        radioButton = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.contactus);
        radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(btnNavBarOnCheckedChangeListener);
        radioButton = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.orderhistory);
        radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(btnNavBarOnCheckedChangeListener);
        return view;
}
 private CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener btnNavBarOnCheckedChangeListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
           int sid=buttonView.getId();
           int hme=R.id.home;
           int abtus=R.id.aboutus;
           int cnt=R.id.contactus;
           int ordr=R.id.orderhistory;
            if (isChecked) {
                if(sid==hme)
                {
                    //some function
                                 }



                else if(sid==abtus)
                {
                    //some function
                }
                else if(sid==cnt)
                {
                              //
                }
                else if(sid==ordr)
                {

                }

            }
        }
    };


}
```

and my actnavbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="60dp"

android:background="@android:color/white"
>
  <RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="#cccccc"       
    >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/home"
        style="@style/navbar_button"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/home_icon"
        android:text="Home"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:gravity="center_horizontal"

       android:textSize="12sp"
       android:textColor="#333333"
        />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/aboutus"
        style="@style/navbar_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="About us"
        android:textSize="12sp"
       android:textColor="#333333"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/aboutus_icon"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

         <RadioButton
           android:id="@+id/contactus"
        style="@style/navbar_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="Contact us"
       android:textColor="#333333"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/contact_icon"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/orderhistory"
        style="@style/navbar_button"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/order_history_icon"
        android:text="Order history"
        android:textSize="12sp"
       android:textColor="#333333"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:gravity="center_horizontal"

            />


       </RadioGroup>



</RelativeLayout>
```

If i use like this I am getting the following logcat error

```
    09-21 14:52:12.466: E/AndroidRuntime(336): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  09-21 14:52:12.466: E/AndroidRuntime(336): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to        
 start activity    

 ComponentInfo{com.androidhive.xmlparsing/com.androidhive.xmlparsing.Listofcategories}:  android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #44: Error inflating class fragment
  09-21 14:52:12.466: E/AndroidRuntime(336):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
       09-21 14:52:12.466: E/AndroidRuntime(336):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
      09-21 14:52:12.466: E/AndroidRuntime(336):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
       09-21 14:52:12.466: E/AndroidRuntime(336):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
        09-21 14:52:12.466: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 09-21 14:52:12.466: E/AndroidRuntime(336):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 09-21 14:52:12.466: E/AndroidRuntime(336):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
 09-21 14:52:12.466: E/AndroidRuntime(336):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 09-21 14:52:12.466: E/AndroidRuntime(336):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
   09-21 14:52:12.466: E/AndroidRuntime(336):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
 09-21 14:52:12.466: E/AndroidRuntime(336):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
 09-21 14:52:12.466: E/AndroidRuntime(336):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 09-21 14:52:12.466: E/AndroidRuntime(336): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #44: Error inflating class fragment
 09-21 14:52:12.466: E/AndroidRuntime(336):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
 09-21 14:52:12.466: E/AndroidRuntime(336):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
 09-21 14:52:12.466: E/AndroidRuntime(336):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
 09-21 14:52:12.466: E/AndroidRuntime(336):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
09-21 14:52:12.466: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
 09-21 14:52:12.466: E/AndroidRuntime(336):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
 09-21 14:52:12.466: E/AndroidRuntime(336):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
  09-21 14:52:12.466: E/AndroidRuntime(336):    at com.androidhive.xmlparsing.Listofcategories.onCreate(Listofcategories.java:97)
    09-21 14:52:12.466: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
  09-21 14:52:12.466: E/AndroidRuntime(336):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
   09-21 14:52:12.466: E/AndroidRuntime(336):   ... 11 more
 09-21 14:52:12.466: E/AndroidRuntime(336): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.androidhive.xmlparsing-1.apk]
  09-21 14:52:12.466: E/AndroidRuntime(336):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
       09-21 14:52:12.466: E/AndroidRuntime(336):   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
       09-21 14:52:12.466: E/AndroidRuntime(336):   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
           09-21 14:52:12.466: E/AndroidRuntime(336):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
  09-21 14:52:12.466: E/AndroidRuntime(336):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:549)
     09-21 14:52:12.466: E/AndroidRuntime(336):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
     09-21 14:52:12.466: E/AndroidRuntime(336):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
    09-21 14:52:12.466: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  ... 20 more
```

Where am i doing the mistake??? Please any suggestions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your class `**fragmentactivity**` is FragmentActivity you can't use it in xml file.

Your code..

```
public class fragmentactivity extends FragmentActivity
```

View class code

```
public class fragmentactivity extends Fragment
```

Only `view class` file can use in `xml` file

that why you facing `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment` error

here many example on Fragment

[Example 1](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/02/android-30-fragments-api.html)

[Example 2](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

[Also look on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710573/need-a-fragments-example)